# Why would getElementsByClassName() work and not querySelector()?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, angular

I'm trying to include an iframe on a careers page within a Ruby on Rails/AngularJS site that is injected dynamically into the page when it loads. Currently, the iframe.js file selects the div, named "jv-careersite" and puts the iframe within that div. My issue is that the javascript provided uses querySelector() and returns null. So I swapped out querySelector() for getElementsByClassName() and it returns an HTML Collection with the element I need.

I've placed the Javascript file in public/app/scripts, and included a link to it within application.html.erb. When I check the Dev Tools, the iframe.js file is loading with 200 OK and content-type is indeed javascript. So what's the issue here?

HTML

```
<div class="careers-iframe">
    <div class="jv-careersite" data-careersite="companyname"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
(function(win) {

var anchor, el, src, baseUrl, optionMap, path;

optionMap = {
    'data-category': 'c',
    'data-department': 'd',
    'data-location': 'l',
    'data-region': 'r',
    'data-subsidiary': 's',
    'data-type': 't'
};

el = document.querySelector('.jv-careersite');
console.log(el);
if (!el) {

    return;
}

if (!el.getAttribute('data-careersite')) {
    warn('Jobvite: no careersite detected!');
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of the following code:

```
el = document.querySelector('.jv-careersite');
```

Is something like (it's `querySelector` and not `querySelectorAll`):

```
el = document.getElementsByClassName('.jv-careersite')[0];
```

The possible reason will be you might have missed the `[0]`, which would have made it into `HTMLCollection` instead of `HTMLElement`.

Or the opposite. In case, if the `getElementsByClassName()` works, then internally, somewhere, it's being appended with `[0]`, which in turn returns `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: When I use getElementsByClassName()[0] it returns undefined. I assume this has something to do with the Javascript being fired before the page is loaded. I tried to fix this problem by surrounding the anonymous function(win) {} with $(document).ready() but querySelector() still returns null. I have a feeling this has something to do with the asset pipeline executing the JS before the actual view is rendered, therefore querySelector() doesn't match anything. I'm new to Rails so I'm not 100% clear on how to add Javascript files to an individual view.

Comment: @quinteno That's a nice research... I believe the same then. Why not try wrapping your code inside `$(function () { // your code here... });`